# Unexpected EOF in mysql shell script

Tags: mysql, shell

I'm getting some mysql info from shell like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
keyOrPass=$1
intercom=$2
flat=$3
number=$4
mysql -ulogin -ppassword db_name << EOF
select codeGuestEmail, codePrivateEmail from mbus_clients WHERE flat=$flat and domophone=$intercom;
EOF
```

I found this solution in some tutorial, but it says:
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EOF'
What's wrong? How can I finish mysql session?
    http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/using-mysql-in-shell-scripts/ here is example of tutorial where I found solution.
**UPDATE** added different quotes to EOF doesn't work too.

Answer (score 1):

in your query pass the dynamic variable with quotes ..

```
select codeGuestEmail, codePrivateEmail from mbus_clients WHERE flat='$flat' and domophone='$intercom';
```

or try with this

```
select codeGuestEmail, codePrivateEmail from mbus_clients WHERE flat=${flat} and domophone=${intercom};
```

Comment: First variant doesn't help moreover with my variant I get proper result in your first don't

Comment: you can also adopt one more approach by writing sql in separate file and set the dynamic variable like 'set @intercom=${intercom}' and then call the sql file from this shell script