# Select into variable or implement select inside select of mysql in shell script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I have such mysql script in shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
keyOrPass=$1
intercom=$2
flat=$3
number=$4
mysql -ulogin -ppassword db_name << EOF
select codeGuestEmail, codePrivateEmail from mbus_clients WHERE flat=$flat and domophone=$intercom;
select * from mbusClientKeys where id_client=(select id from mbus_clients WHERE flat=${flat} and domophone=${intercom});
EOF
```

It gives mistake when I add second query:  `right syntax to use near ''` When I try to declare variable and use select into as it is in stored procedure this doesn't work too. Also mistake with EOF from [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585070/unexpected-eof-in-mysql-shell-script) is actual.
**UPDATE**
My attempt doens't works too:

```
SET @id := 1;
select id into @id from mbus_clients WHERE flat=${flat} and domophone=${intercom};
```

says

```
right syntax to use near 'select id into @id from mbus_clients WHERE flat=200
```

**UPDATE2**
missed semicolon in previous update.
Works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @id := 1;
```

set works fine, but not 
`set id=1` as it is in stored procedures should be `:=`